# Indexing files linked in a flexform field with solrfal 3.1.0 in TYPO3 7.6

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions

We have an old TYPO3 7.6 installation with a custom content element which uses flexform fields (saved in the pi_flexform field). It has an RTE field included in this. If you link to a file in that RTE field it is not indexed by solrfal (3.1.0). In a normal content element (with text in the bodytext field) it does work.

I've already tried adding the following to TypoScript without succes:

```
plugin.tx_solr {
  index {
    enableFileIndexing {
      pageContext {
        contentElementTypes {
          fluidcontent_content = pi_flexform
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to add this flexform field to solrfal so linked files are indexed?

P.S. I know the versions are old and it should be updated.